# Mastermind in java - right color in the wrong position

Tags: java

I'm looking to write Mastermind in Java.

The code works (apparently), but is there a way to code the "right color in the wrong position" (white) in a shorter way instead of what I've done (pratically listing every color)? Maybe another loop?

If you need to know the formula for the white, I found it here: [Mastermind formula](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/Mastermind.shtml).

```
public class Game {

private static int white = 0;
private static int colors = 4;

static int[] colorsArray = {
    1,2,3,4
};
static int[] randomArray = new int[colors];
static int[] userArray = new int[colors];

static int isWhite(int[] randomArray, int[] userArray){

    int n1, n2, n3, n4 =0;      
    int m1, m2, m3, m4 =0;

    //HERE'S THE PROBLEM
    for(int i=0; i<colorsArray.length; i++){

        //n userArray
        if(colorsArray[0] == userArray[i]){
            n1++;
        }
        if(colorsArray[1] == userArray[i]){
            n2++;
        }
        if(colorsArray[2] == userArray[i]){
            n3++;
        }
        if(colorsArray[3] == userArray[i]){
            n4++;
        }

        //m randomArray
        if(colorsArray[0] == randomArray[i]){
            m1++;
        }
        if(colorsArray[1] == randomArray[i]){
            m2++;
        }
        if(colorsArray[2] == randomArray[i]){
            m3++;
        }
        if(colorsArray[3] == randomArray[i]){
            m4++;
        }

        white = (Math.min(n1, m1) + Math.min(n2, m2) + Math.min(n3, m3) + Math.min(n4, m4)) - black;
    }
    return white;
}
...other code
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question should have been posted on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't know, maybe I can edit the question putting just the "white" function to shorten it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two more arrays `ns` and `ms` that are each four elements long. Inside your for loop, make another nested for loop that runs through all four elements say with the index `j`.

```
if (colorsArray[j] == userArray[i])
    ns[j]++;

if (colorsArray[j] == randomArray[i])
    ms[j]++;
```

Then finish up with one more for loop that computes the minimum between each element of your two arrays `ns` and `ms`.